# Scala code build with sbt assembly , failing

Tags: scala, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt 0.13.7  and Scala 2.11.4 on a Windows machine to compile my code into a fat jar, that I eventually want to run on a Linux machine.

Below is my build.sbt file:

```
import AssemblyKeys._

name := "Simple Project"
version := "1.0"
organization := "com.myorg"
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Spark dependency
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0" % "provided",
  // Third party libraries
  "net.sf.jopt-simple" % "jopt-simple" % "4.3",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.0"
)
libraryDependencies += Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.7.2", "0.11.2", "2.9.1")
// This statement includes the assembly plugin capabilities
assemblySettings
// Configure jar named used with the assembly plug-in
jarName in assembly := "my-project-assembly.jar"
// A special option to exclude Scala itself form our assembly jar, since Spark
// already bundles Scala.
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

The error I am facing is:

```
 build.sbt:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[sbt.Project.Setting[_]]
 required: sbt.internals.DslEntry
assemblySettings
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: What version of the sbt-native-packager plugin are you specifying? The code you provided works with 1.0.0-M4 on a MBP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using sbt-assembly 0.12.0? If so, you don't need `assemblySettings` any more since it's an [auto plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html).

**Edit**:

You have to include

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

in `project/*.sbt` like `project/assembly.sbt`, not `build.sbt`.

Comment: Eugene , when I include following line in build.sbt                                                                               addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")       it fails to find it on maven repo                                  [warn]                                                                https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.11_0.13/0.12
.0/sbt-assembly-0.12.0.pom

Comment: So I looked into repo and included                            libraryDependencies += Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.7.2", "0.11.2", "2.9.1")                         Which works but seems like a very old version

Comment: sbt plugins are on the sbt community repo - http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.12.0/

Comment: ok. Could you hit the checkbox and accept my answer please, so this question doesn't show up as an unanswered question?

Comment: Hmm. I seem to have a problem with the new plug-in. SBT isn't complaining about finding the assembly jar, but the assembly task doesn't show up when I start SBT. Here's what I have in project/assembly.sbt:

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")

Comment: In build.sbt, I have:

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
  "Sonatype releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2"
 )

I have SBT 0.13.7, so the auto-plugin should work. 

Also, it seems to me like the Bintray directory structure wouldn't match the path passed into the above addSbtPlugin call. Any idea why the new plugin's task isn't showing up?

Comment: If this is an issue of adding enablePlugins(), how does that work in build.sbt, as opposed to Build.scala? Any other reason(s) why the plugin's task is invisible?

Comment: BTW, I did follow the migration guide for build.sbt for SBT 0.13.6+: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/Migration.md